# How to match variably co-occurring patterns in R

Tags: r, regex

My question relates to matching co-occurring patterns in texts.
For example, in this vector:

```
x <- c("oh well i didn't know that",                        # not match
       "yeah right that's true",                            # not match
       "okay, so she lives in, well, i guess soho",         # not match
       "well, uh oh, okay in that case",                    # match
       "okay, right, well oh why not")                      # match
```

I would like to match those strings in which the words `well`, `oh`, and `okay` co-occur **in any order**. I've come up with this regex, which, however, incorrectly also matches `"okay, so she lives in, well, i guess soho"` (confusingly, despite the fact that I've used word boundary anchors `\\b` for `oh`):

```
grep("(?=\\boh\\b)*(?=\\bwell\\b)*(?=\\bokay\\b).*", x, perl = T, value = T) 
# "okay, so she lives in, well, i guess soho"  "well, uh oh, okay in that case"  "okay, right, well oh why not"
```

How can this regex be tweaked to match all and any strings in which `well`, `oh`, and `okay` co-occur as *words*?

Comment: `"^(?=.*\\boh\\b)(?=.*\\bwell\\b)(?=.*\\bokay\\b)"` - anchor the match at the start of string and allow any text before each word. You made the first two lookaheads optional, so no wonder you get "false positives".

Comment: Okay, thanks for this.